# Area51 Creating Sites On Stack Exchange

Tags: small-communities

How do you build a q&a stack exchange site? i tried area 51, but there's no way to do it. I am trying some sites now and might not need your help soon.

Comment: You're supposed to build a community before you head over to Area51.  Do you have a community?